# How to get JSON response after ajax method POST

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, rest

I make a post request to my rest controller and as a result I want to get information about the error in case of incorrect data. Error information is generated in `@RestControllerAdvice`.
Here is my advice class:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestControllerErrorHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public Map<String, Object> handleCustomerException(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
        Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        body.put("timestamp", new Date());
        body.put("exception", "MethodArgumentNotValidException");

        List<String> errors = exception
                .getBindingResult()
                .getFieldErrors()
                .stream()
                .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        body.put("errors", errors);
        return body;
    }
}
```

Here is the result of the error that I get.

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-07-07T20:20:44.778+00:00",
  "exception": "MethodArgumentNotValidException",
  "errors": [
    "Login length: 6 - min and 10 - max",
    "Password length: 6 - min and 10 - max"
  ]
}
```

This is how I call method POST from ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sendForm").click(function () {
        const login = $('input[name=login]').val();
        const password = $('input[name=password]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/users",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({"login": login, "password": password}),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success: ' + data.id + " " + data.login + " " + data.password)
            },
            error: function (requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
                alert(error);//this field return "error" string
                alert(errorThrown);//for some reason this is empty when I get an error
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**How can I read it to get exactly the error information?** I want to display this: `"Login length: 6 - min and 10 - max", "Password length: 6 - min and 10 - max"` in `alert()`.

Answer (score 0):

so, what you should note - the response is an object (array-like) which has a subkey named `errors` which itself contains the data (non-keyed array). So, you should change the Ajax success part to this:

```
success: function (data) {
    var parsed_response = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(parsed_response.errors[0]+ " " + parsed_response.errors[1]);
},
```

as you see, with parsed response, you get the access to the members of the object.

---

update:

if you want to get the error response, that it means the "response object" (which contained timespamp, exception, errors... members) you had prepared for your response, doesnt matter, as it will not be returned in that (erroneus) situation. So, in that case, as you already mentioned, you are getting `alert` of the error message, and depending on that (i.e. 404, 410, ...) it will tell you what happens on backend. you will not get any response in that case, because "error" function itself says that server didn't return the readable (outputed) answer, and you have to fix that error (i.e. 410, 503 or whatever, search for them in google).
I might also suggest to save debug file in backend language when receiving the ajax request, so you will find out in which line the backend code breaks.

i.e.

```
save_to_file("a1");
your codes
save_to_file("a2");
your another codes
save_to_file("a3");
```

and so on...

so, some of the backend code has error.

Comment: When response status is OK(200) `success` block works. In this case, I get the data that I wanted to save in JSON format. But I'm looking for other how to get error message when response was BAD_REQUEST or another and in this case `error` block works.

Comment: @IljaTarasovs i have updated my answer. that is all i could understand from your explained situation. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

```
error: function (requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
    const result = JSON.parse(requestObject.responseText);
    alert('error: ' + result.errors[0]);//"Login length: 6 - min and 10 - max"
}
```